# How to advertize BLE custom data in Linux

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, linux

I'm learning BLE and slightly got stuck with advertisements. I'm trying to advertise custom data representing an iBeacon with the commands below:

```
bluetoothctl
menu advertise
manufacturer 0x4C 0x00 0x02 0x15 0xE2 0x0A 0x39 0xF4 0x73 0xF5 0x4B 0xC4 0xA1 0x2F 0x17 0xD1 0xAD 0x07 0xA9 0x61 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x2a
back
advertise broadcast
```

On another side I have iBeacons' locator that does not find the beacon, so I deduce I setup advertisement incorrectly.
`bluetoothctl` seems not to be the best documented tool and I cannot find any hits

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67758943